# Efficient Argmin in C++11

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a vector of elements, and I can calculate a single number from each of the elements using a very expensive function. I would like the element which maps to the lowest of these numbers. I know how to do this in C++03: *

```
Foo get_lowest(const std::vector<Foo> &foos) {
  double lowest_so_far = std::numeric_limits<double>::max();
  std::vector<Foo>::iterator best;
  for(std::vector<Foo>::iterator i = foos.begin(); i != foos.end(); i++) {
    const double curr_val = i->bar();
     if( curr_val < lowest_so_far ) { 
       best = i;
       lowest_so_far = curr_val
     }
  }

  return *i;
}
```

I could also do this using `std::min_element`, except the naive way of doing things (calling `Foo::bar` and returning a boolean from `<`) calls `Foo::bar` more times than the code I posted above. I could pre-calculate each of these values and then use `std::min_element`, except that this code is more complicated than the above code.

In Going Native, someone (Sean Parent, thanks SChepurin!) said that a good style guide for modern C++ is to avoid "raw loops". Is there a more C++11 idiomatic way of doing what I want?

* I just typed this into the window, I didn't even try to compile it.

Comment: Typically, "raw arrays" opposed to [`<algorithm>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/algorithm) functions.

Comment: @Drop I'm sorry, I don't understand. What about raw arrays?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "calls `Foo::bar` more times than the code I posted ...".  Your code is basically implementing the same thing as http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/min_element/

Comment: @anjruu You've asked: "Is there a more C++11 idiomatic way of doing what I want?". Answer is: algorithms + lambda as predicate maybe. Sometimes its faster than loop. But this isn't answer to your main question.

Comment: `std::min_element(foos.begin(), foos.end(), [](const Foo& a, const Foo& b) { return a.bar() < b.bar();});`

This calls bar more often than the hand-crafted code, since it calls bar twice per comparison, whereas the hand-crafted code calls bar only once per comparison.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: `min_element` does `N-1` *comparisons*, with 2 calls for `bar` each time, while his implementation has exactly `N` calls for `bar` - which is less than `2N-2` if `N>2` ;)

Comment: @anjruu - Sean Parent (not Herb Sutter) mentioned that using algorithms (implemented in <algorithm>) + lambda is more efficient in most cases than "raw loops" we all accustomed to write.

Comment: @anjruu Can you cache result of `bar()` in `Foo`, so on second call cached value returns? If you can, please compare results of hand-crafted and and algo one. It's interesting, but I'm too lazy to code now (((

Comment: @Drop Oh, that's interesting, I hadn't thought of that. Then I could use `std::min_element` without so much of a cost. Good idea.

Comment: @anjruu And if we dig a little more, you can drag implementation of `bar()` into predicate, so you will have external function `bar_compare(foo1, foo2)` or member `foo1.bar(foo2)` or overloaded `operator<()` (if suitable), and, probably, could optimize comparison inside expensive algorithm itself. One simple example comes in mind: comparison of lengths of 3D vectors: inside comparison function you can compare squares of lengths directly and not calculate square roots.

Comment: If I were you I'd just take your loop there and generalize it to an iterator range and an arbitrary function: make your own stl-like algorithm and then reuse it everywhere!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If calling `Foo::bar` is **really** such a big deal in terms of performance (see juancho's note to profiling), I'd first calculate a vector of the `bar` values and then search for the `min_index` there:

```
Foo const& get_lowest(const std::vector<Foo> &foos) {
  typedef decltype(foos[0].bar()) BarVal;

  std::vector<BarVal> barValues;
  barValues.reserve(foos.size());

  std::transform(begin(foos), end(foos), std::back_inserter(barValues), [](Foo const& f) {
    return f.bar(); 
  });

  auto barPos = std::min_element(begin(barValues), end(barValues));
  auto fooPos = begin(foos) + std::distance(begin(barValues), barPos);
  return *fooPos;
}
```

Update: another approach would be using `std::accumulate` with a lambda to do exactly what you handcoded, but that would involve housekeeping and rely on side effecets of the lambda, making the code less comprehensible.

Comment: Suggestion, `std::mem_fn(&Foo::bar)` instead of the lambda.

Comment: Given that `Foo` has only one overload of `bar`, that would be an alternative, yes.

Answer (score 4):

This is an interesting one: determining a property based on an expensive operation at a position is not immediately supported. Using a version of `std::min_element()` which would do the computations in each call to the binary predicate isn't quite the way to go: you don't want to recompute the value of the current known minimum. It may be warranted to write a custom loop.

In general, the STL algorithms assume that getting the value at a position is fairly cheap. Likewise, the iterator operations (advance, test, dereference) should be fast. The somewhat costly operation is assumed to be the comparison in this example. When uses match these use caes, STL algorithms are probably indeed a better option, e.g., because they can do all kinds of crazy things (loop unrolling, memory operations, etc.). I certainly agree with Herb's statement to use *what* to do rather than *how* to do it but for your case I don't think the STL algorithms can do it efficiently.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want an iterator on the best `Foo`, you could go with a `for_each`:

```
Foo *get_lowest(const std::vector<Foo> &foos) {

    Foo *best = nullptr;
    double lowest_so_far = std::numeric_limits<double>::max();
    std::for_each(begin(foos), end(foos), [&](Foo &i){
        const double curr_val = i.bar();
        if (curr_val < lowest_so_far) {
            lowest_so_far = curr_val;
            best = &i;
        }
    });

    return best; // Return a "Foo *" to handle the empty vector case
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I recall correctly, Sean Parent also suggested to write your own algorithm if you do not find one suitable in the STL. You call bar only once per element and you do not have to store its value. I guess the main idea is the separation concerns between the algorithm and your application code.

```
template<class ForwardIterator, class Cost>
ForwardIterator min_cost_element(ForwardIterator first, ForwardIterator last, Cost cost)
{
    typedef decltype(cost(iterator_traits<ForwardIterator>::value_type())) value_t;

    if(first == last)
        return last;
    value_t lowest = cost(*first);
    ForwardIterator found = first;
    while(++first != last) {
        value_t val = cost(*first);
        if(val < lowest) {
            lowest = val;
            found = first;
        }
    }
    return found;
}

const Foo& get_lowest(const vector<Foo>& foos) {
    assert(!foos.empty());
    return *min_cost_element(foos.begin(), foos.end(), mem_fn(&Foo::bar));
}
```

Given the return type of the cost function returns a type that supports less than, the algorithm is generic and supports an empty range.

To be thorough, I investigated first the possibility to use the standard min_element:

```
const Foo& get_lowest_wierd(const vector<Foo>& foos) {
    struct predicate {
        double lowest;
        predicate(const Foo& first) : lowest(first.bar()) {}
        bool operator()(const Foo& x, const Foo&) {
            auto val = x.bar();
            if(val < lowest) {
                lowest = val;
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    };

    assert(!foos.empty());
    return *min_element(foos.cbegin(), foos.cend(), predicate(foos.front()));
}
```

But I find this solution clumsy:

1. it relies too much on an interpretation of the definition from the standard "Returns
   the first iterator i in the range [first, last) such that for every
   iterator j in the range [first, last) the conditions hold: comp(*j,
   *i) == false", i.e. the "candidate" minimum is always on the right hand side
2. because of the previous point, the predicate has to be defined localy: it does not work outside of this context.
3. It does not work in Debug mode with VS2013 because of the checks on the predicate to ensure Compare defines strick weak ordering (eventhough I am not sure it is required here) but it works fine in release.

Both code samples compile under VS2013. Both return the same value as the function in the question (once the typo were fixed).

Answer (score 0):

not really an answer, but solution to your problem: why dont you cache result of bar inside the object? 
aka

```
double bar()
{
  if (bar_calculated)
      return bar_val;
   //...
}
```

BTW regarding avoiding raw loops:
you need to avoid them when you need equivalent code as you would get by using STL algs. If you have special req and you cant customize alg to suit your needs use raw loop. :)
For example here *I think* you could have stateful comparator that remembers the current arg_min address so it can cache its value... but that is bending the design just to use alg.